# How to make compile function obey my .bashrc when compile is called by some library?

Tags: bash

In my `~/.bashrc` I've got some changes, the most important one being the change to `$PATH`. One of the commands I'm using runs through the `compile` function, but it fails - bash can't find the binary.

Because I can run the binary just find from the command line, and the path to the binary is added to `$PATH` in my `.bashrc`, I think that `compile` doesn't read my `.bashrc` and thus can't find the binary it needs to run.

The `compile` function is called by some library to call some other program from shell, so I'd rather not modify the original code.

How can I make `compile` run the .bashrc first to fix this problem?

Comment: If you have not changed the compile command away from `make`, you could just change it to `source ~/.bashrc && make`.

Comment: @icarus see the edit - the compile is called by other library, and not used to call make.

Comment: How are you invoking emacs? Does `M-x getenv` `PATH` show your modified PATH? If the issue is just PATH could you fix it with `M-x setenv`? Sorry not to be directly answering your question.